# How to router.navigate to same route in Angular 4 and catch the same event?

Tags: javascript, angular, routes, angular-ui-router

Okay, I have two use cases for my question here:

1. I'm working on an application which has a `/en/register` route. It all works good when I'm at the root and I click a button that does `this.router.navigate([this.routeParams.lang, 'register']);` and it's all good, this opens up a modal in the constructor (or ngOnInit, anyways) with `($('#modalRegister') as any).modal('show');`.

   It all works good, but if I close the modal, the route is still `/en/register/` (yeah I can make it go to `/en` but see the use case #2 before you suggest this), so when I click the button, it doesn't do anything. Neither the constructor or ngOnInit are being called, **not even** **route.params.subscribe()** or **route.url.subscribe()** (which I think they should...).
2. In the same application, I have a button that does a search and centers some markers in a map (in `/en/search/blah`). That's all good if I'm in the index page *or* if I change the search query. However, if the user drags the map somewhere else and wants to have the same markers centered again, I also do `this.router.navigate(['search', this.searchQuery]);` and if it ends up being the same route (click the search button twice, for instance) it doesn't do anything.

While I agree it's good so the components don't get recreated if the URL hasn't changed, this is a bad design because in UI-router you could do the same thing and it'd work (as far as I can remember).

So, in Angular 4, how do I run the same code in the constructor/ngOnInit of the route's component when the same URL is being told to be navigated to? or how do I detect if the URL is the same and act accordingly? (although I still think it's bad design, but anyway...).

Any advice is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Whoever -1'd it, at least give a PROPER reason to do so, else you're just being unhelpful.

Comment: Do you know about `Location`? https://angular.io/api/common/Location It should handle this for you

Comment: @Z.Bagley thanks for your suggestion, but noting from what ```Location``` does, it seems it's similar to location.reload() and similar, which is not what I'm looking for :P I wanted to run the same events in the current iteration, not reload the page :(

Answer (score 10):

When I needed to "reload" the current component's constructor and ngOnInit functions, 
the only solution I found was kind of a workaround:

I used the fact that "this.router.navigate" returns a promise. 
So I navigated somewhere else, and returned. It's a bit ugly but it works and the UI is not affected:

```
this.router.navigate(..[somewhere else]..)
    .then(()=>{this.router.navigate(..back..)})
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Yes, its really look ugly... But works for me. Is there any other solution you get?

Answer (score 3):

For case 1,

Why do you navigate to a new route just to open a modal. Just do it being at the same route with a function call. If you want to move to a new route then you can again call `this.router.navigate("/")` in modal close event.

For case 2,
Hope this will work.

```
currentSearchQuery: string;

ngOnInit() {
  this.route.paramMap
    .switchMap((params: ParamMap) => {
        this.currentSearchQuery = params.get('searchQuery');
        updateMarkers();
      });

}
```

Answer (score 2):

i use this workaround

```
this.router.navigate(['path']).then(()=>  {window.location.reload();});
```

Comment: Good shout! In my case, I needed a parameter: `this.router.navigate(['/path', param]).then(() => { window.location.reload(); });`

Comment: This answer just saved me. Thanks!!

Comment: This this.router.navigate(['path']).then(()=>  {window.location.reload();}); approach helped me and worked for me. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Just add dummy parameter at the end of the route /en/register/jk2h4-42hj-234n2-234dfg or query parameter like /en/register?val=jk2h4-42hj-234n2-234dfg

change the parameter value when calling the same route. So browser knows that URL change and Angualr component start to work from full life cycle.

Comment: It's not working, Angular track it as a unmatch URL and redirect to default route