# How to refresh component when navigate to same route?

Tags: angular

I have this:

```
  this.activatedRoute.queryParams.subscribe((params: Params) => {
            if (localStorage.getItem('queryParams')) {
                this.queryParams = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('queryParams'));
                if (this.queryParams[Object.keys(this.queryParams)[0]]) {
                    this.procesId = this.queryParams[Object.keys(this.queryParams)[0]];
                }
            }
})
```

I want to triger queryParams when i click on same route. Any suggestion how can i do that? I have menu so when i click on same link i want to reload that other component where i do something in queryParams. But right now its triggering only when route is change.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46385475/how-to-router-navigate-to-same-route-in-angular-4-and-catch-the-same-event

Comment: yes but these are some workarounds

Answer (score 0):

If you want to reload a component when you navigate to another component, you can do it like this:

first Component:

```
import {Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';

export class ComponentOne implements OnInit {
     constructor() {//some stuff here}

     ngOnInit() {
          //here the code you want to trigger by nagivating to the second component
     }
}
```

second Component:

```
import {Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {ComponentOne} from 'path_to_first_component';

    export class ComponentTwo implements OnInit {
         constructor(private firstComponent: ComponentOne) {} //dependency injection

         ngOnInit() {
              this.firstComponent.ngOnInit(); //this will call the ngOnInit from the first component
         }
    }
```

Comment: This is not the way to access components in template.

Comment: This was not his question, he's asking how to reload component when he clicks