# Angular 6 : How to get router event even when navigated to same route

Tags: angular

How to get router event even when navigated to same route, for examples I have three route

- route1
- route2
- route3

How can I catch event from Router while navigating to route1 from route 1, same route.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to router.navigate to same route in Angular 4 and catch the same event?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46385475/how-to-router-navigate-to-same-route-in-angular-4-and-catch-the-same-event)

Answer (score 5):

Start by telling to reload the routing (i.e. replay the observable) :

```
this.router.onSameUrlNavigation = 'reload';
```

Then, subscribe to route events (and optionally check for the event to be the last of the cycle, otherwise you will make a lot of things) :

```
this.router.events
  .pipe(filter(event => event instanceof NavigationEnd))
  .subscribe(event => {...});
```

Comment: thanks trichetriche :) I got it by configuring it on router module.

Comment: Okay, be careful, configuring the whole router will apply to all routes though.

Comment: ohh, I didnt think in that way, i'll go with your solution thn.

Answer (score 0):

I got it, Thanks anyway, I used following config

```
@NgModule({
    imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes, {onSameUrlNavigation: 'reload'})],
    exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule {

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this using any following way.

1) Just add this line following line in constructor

```
this.router.onSameUrlNavigation = 'reload';
```

this work with RouterModule.forRoot() and  with RouterModule.forChild() both.

2) following line of code will only work with RouterModule.forRoot(), not with RouterModule.forChild(). Because RouterModule.forChild() accepts only one parameter with it.

```
@NgModule({
    imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes,{onSameUrlNavigation: 'reload'})],

    exports: [RouterModule]
})

export class AppRoutingModule {
}
```